# jQuery's .hide() not working?

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to create a list of things that is able to be filtered (via jQuery's .hide()), but it's not working.

jsFiddle (HTML code is too long to be posted here): http://jsfiddle.net/DTXHd/

Example:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $("div .retired").hide();
});
```

Comment: Try `$("div.retired").hide();`

Comment: As a side note...  in the future, please post RELEVANT code.   You could have easily posted your code here by removing 99% of the unnecessary div elements in order to demonstrate the issue.  We did not need to see that you have hundreds of lines of the same code :)

Comment: One MORE side note... your `<button>` does NOT belong in the `<head>` section.   It should be moved to the `<body>` section.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
    $(".retired").hide();
});
```

Use just `.retired`

[Online example](http://jsfiddle.net/JdAGh/)

*Note:* The `.on()` method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), and [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/). To remove events bound with `.on()`, see [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.retired").hide();
```

Remove the space. It looks like you're trying to hide all divs with class `retired`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DTXHd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You gave one extra space between 'div' and class 'retired'.

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $("div.retired").hide();
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/alaminopu/DTXHd/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $("div.retired").hide();
});
```

Remove the space in `div .retired`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space that doesn't belong in your selector.

The code should looks like this:

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
    $("div.retired").hide();
});
```

This means to select divs with a class of retired.   When you include the space, it means something else...  elements with a class of retired that are children of div elements.

Here's your updated Fiddle...
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DTXHd/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn").click(function () {
$(".retired").hide();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DTXHd/4/

You can use this. If you want to select a div according to its class ,you use `.yourclassname` . If you want to select a div according to its id , you use `#yourid`.